# Select a subset of mysql database column - date

Tags: mysql, substring, subset

I have a query:

```
select post_name, post_title, post_date from mysite.wp_posts where post_status='publish'
```

`post_date` outputs a GMT date and time like: `2016-12-17 17:07:26`

I want to select just `2016` and just `12` via the mysql query and not the rest.

How can i modify my query to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them in separate columns:

```
SELECT post_name,
  post_title,
  YEAR(post_date) YEAR,
  MONTH(post_date) MONTH
FROM mysite.wp_posts
WHERE post_status='publish';
```

If in same column like `2016-12`:

```
SELECT post_name,
  post_title,
  date_format(post_date, '%Y-%m') year_month
FROM mysite.wp_posts
WHERE post_status='publish';
```

Comment: Really, really helpful. Thanks.